# Using a transform to build a drawer

Tags: html, css

In the following codepen I have a drawer that open/closes by clicking on the header. The mechanism by which this works is a CSS transform which sets the drawer contents to `translate3d(0, calc(-100% - 0.7em), 0);`

When closed. Currently content below the drawer is pushed down by the height of the drawer items when they are hidden.

I would like the height of the closed drawer to be the height of the button when closed.

What am I doing wrong?

https://codepen.io/matthewp/pen/YRzjvP

Comment: What exactly is the issue here ? from what i see in the pen you provided, everything is fine.

Comment: Is this what you're looking for: `.drawer { height: 0; } .drawer.open { height: auto; }`

Comment: @ZohirSalak Scroll down and see where "Fruit" is displayed. I would like it to be directly under the "Green" button.

Comment: scroll what exactly ? there's no overflow.

Comment: Scroll the page.  You'll see that "Fruit" is far down. When you open the drawer you will see why.

Comment: @MyiEye That's a good idea but doesn't quite work with the animation. Preferably opening the drawer should push down the content below as part of the animation.

Comment: there's no overflow, nothing to scroll. as a side note, transform property is merely a visual effect, it doesn't affect other elements.

Comment: @ZohirSalak I think you're hung up on the scrolling. Maybe you have a larger monitor than me. So forget about scrolling. Do you see where "Fruit" appears, that it appears far below "Colors" when the drawer is closed? That is the issue, I do not want it to be pushed down that far when the drawer is closed.

Comment: You will have to transition the height to achieve that, and that is a another deep rabbit hole.

Comment: You might wanna check this [article](https://css-tricks.com/using-css-transitions-auto-dimensions/)

Comment: Perhaps this: `.drawer { max-height: 0;
 transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(0,1,0,1);
} .drawer.open { max-height: 9999px;
 transition: max-height 0.3s cubic-bezier(1,0,1,0);
}` (taken from a comment in the article linked to by @Zohir Salak)

Answer (score 1):

Just put the h2 inside the `.drawer` div and adjust the amount of `translate` accordingly.

```js
let drawer = document.querySelector('.drawer');
let btn = document.querySelector('#open-drawer');

btn.addEventListener('click', ev => {
  drawer.classList.toggle('open');
  btn.classList.toggle('open');
});
```

```css
html, body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

body {
  font-family: -apple-system,BlinkMacSystemFont,"Segoe UI",Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif,"Apple Color Emoji","Segoe UI Emoji","Segoe UI Symbol";
}

p {
  line-height: 1.5;
}

main {
  /* width: 800px; */
  margin: auto;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 3fr 1fr;
  grid-column-gap: 1em;
}

main > header {
  grid-column: 1 / 3;
  text-align: center;
}

aside {
  background-color: rgb(244, 245, 247);
  padding: 0.7em;
}

.display-drawer {
  display: block;
  justify-self: center;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.display-drawer h4 {
  margin: 0;
  text-align: left;
}

.items {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.items:first-of-type {
  margin-top: 0.8em;
}

.items li {
  margin-bottom: 0.2em;
}

.items li button {
  border: 0;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  border-radius: 4px;
  padding: 0.3em;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: start;
}

.wrapper {
  background-color: inherit;
  overflow: hidden;
}

.counter {
  z-index: 2;
  position: relative;
  background-color: inherit;
}

button {
  border: 0;
  background: transparent;
  font-size: 100%;
  font-family: inherit;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0.4em;
  width: 100%;

  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

button:not(:focus-visible) {
  outline: none;
}

button .arrow {
  transition: 0.25s;
  transition-style: preserve-3d;
}

button .arrow:after {
  content: '⌃';
}

button.open .arrow {
  transform: rotateX(180deg);
}

.drawer {
  transition: transform .25s ease-out;
  transform: translate3d(0, calc(-100% + 2em), 0); /* changed size */
  z-index: 1;
  background-color: inherit;
}

.drawer.open {
  transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);
}

hr {
  border: 3px solid #cfd3d7;
  margin: 0.7em 0;
}

.color-red button {
  background-color: red;
}

.color-green button {
  background-color: green;
}

.color-purple button {
  background-color: purple;
}

.color-magneta button {
  background-color: magenta;
}

.color-blue button {
  background-color: blue;
}

.color-yellow button {
  background-color: yellow;
}

.color-orange button {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <header>
    <h1>Some App</h1>
  </header>

  <div class="content">
    <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. In aliquet massa quis ipsum faucibus, tincidunt euismod lectus posuere. Aenean bibendum nisi hendrerit tortor efficitur, ut luctus ex aliquet. Fusce auctor fermentum orci at elementum. Aliquam posuere vel quam vel pellentesque. Integer blandit, urna a tincidunt gravida, eros nisi condimentum neque, eget rutrum nisl lorem vel urna. Sed eget efficitur dui. Fusce quam mi, fermentum sit amet porta id, rhoncus a turpis. Duis vitae neque gravida, bibendum neque non, vehicula mi. Sed ornare nunc sed egestas faucibus. In a efficitur metus.</p>
    <p>Pellentesque consequat nec mi vitae tincidunt. Mauris cursus libero in massa dictum aliquam. Vestibulum faucibus dictum nunc, id consequat nisi fringilla sed. Pellentesque sed faucibus lectus. Nam tempus luctus consequat. Pellentesque habitant morbi tristique senectus et netus et malesuada fames ac turpis egestas. Duis sit amet ligula a orci posuere volutpat non sit amet tellus. Aenean luctus ornare aliquet. Integer suscipit ornare sapien, nec interdum nibh fermentum molestie. Mauris blandit mauris at suscipit vehicula.</p>
  </div>

  <aside>
    <div class="display-drawer wrapper">
      <div class="counter">
        <button id="open-drawer" type="button">
          <h4 class="header">Colors</h4>
          <span class="arrow"></span>
        </button>
        <ul class="items selected">
          <li class="color-red">
            <button type="button">Red</button>
          </li>
          <li class="color-green">
            <button type="button">Green</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="drawer">
        <hr />
        <ul class="items unselected">
          <li class="color-blue">
            <button type="button">Blue</button>
          </li>
          <li class="color-purple">
            <button type="button">Purple</button>
          </li>
          <li class="color-magneta">
            <button type="button">Magneta</button>
          </li>
          <li class="color-yellow">
            <button type="button">Yellow</button>
          </li>
          <li class="color-orange">
            <button type="button">Orange</button>
          </li>
        </ul>
        <h2>Fruit</h2> <!-- changed position -->
      </div>
    </div>
  </aside>
</main>
```

Please note that I also disabled the width of `main` in the snippet, but that was just to make it fit in the window here without having to go full screen. (The changes that matter are marked with comments.)

Comment: The aside doesn't collapse.

Comment: @ZohirSalak The OP wanted the drawer to collapse, not the whole article! At least, that's what I understood. Unless they put the `drawer` class on the wrong element.